# how to add a user define extension effect in webserver

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, download

My JSP page is

```
<a href="xxx.lice">xx.lice</a>
```

I want the user to download the file, not open it when the link is clicked.

I tried putting the "lice" extension in tomcat `web.xml` and nothing happened.

```
<mime-mapping> 
    <extension>lic</extension> 
    <mime-type>application/lic</mime-type> 
</mime-mapping>`
```

I also tried another approach below and nothing happened

```
  function openfile(url)   {   
      var a =window.open(url,"_blank","");   
      a.document.execCommand("SaveAs");   
      a.close();   
  }

  <a href="#" onclick='openfile('xxx.lice')' />
```

Then I tried in previous page add some code below, dialog exist, but other information cannot be seen, I want people to click the `<a>` tag then begin popup "saveas" dialog.

```
      String url = request.getRequestURL().substring(0,request.getRequestURL().lastIndexOf("/")+1) + "upload/xxx.lice";
//            //set .lic to mime type
//            String filename = "xxx.lice";
//            String mimeType = new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(filename);
//            response.setContentType( mimeType);
//            response.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="
//                    + filename );
            request.setAttribute("message", "Upload has been done successfully!\r\n The new license file is<a href=\""+ url +"\" >xxx.lice</a>");
```

Comment: The code at the bottom ought to work. Can you provide some context to where you added it? Not in a JSP-file, right? In a servlet, perhaps?

Comment: the bottom code is written in java servlet .sorry I forgot it.

Comment: No problem. Can you include the code where you write the file to the response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  function openfile(url)   {   
      var a =window.open(url,"_blank","");   
  }

  <a href="#" onclick="openfile('SownloadLiceFileServlet')" />
```

and in that Servlet

```
  //set .lic to mime type
  String filename = "xxx.lice";
  String mimeType = new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(filename);
  response.setContentType( mimeType);
  response.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename );
  // Read the file content as a byte array
  java.io.File liceFile = new java.io.File("[File Path]");
  byte[] fileBytes = new byte[(int)liceFile.length()];
  java.io.FileInputStream liceFileStream = new java.io.FileInputStream(liceFile);
  liceFileStream.read(fileBytes);
  liceFileStream.close();
  //Push that byte array to the browser (user).
  ServletOutputStream sos = response.getOutputStream();
  sos.write(fileBytes);
```

Comment: Ravindra ,thank you very much.I create a servlet and question solved!thanks henrik

Comment: Very Good. You can follow the same approach with JSP also. However, as JSP should be designed as light weight component, better to use servlet only.

Comment: Also accept and upvote the answer which helped you to solve your problem.

Comment: my reputation is not reach 15 ,so i can not vote the best answer . I will do it later .:D